# Passing information from prepare to converge and verify step

Tags: ansible, molecule

I use [molecule](https://molecule.readthedocs.io) for end-to-end testing ansible roles that interact with kubernetes clusters.

Due to the fact that spinning up a kubernetes cluster (with additional features I need for my tests) to get a clean environment for each test is very time consuming (up to 45 minutes), I have pre-provisioned a few clusters and created an API which tells me which clusters are available for testing purposes.

In my molecule tests I use the delegated driver with a local connection, so the tests are being run on my local machine or the CI runner.

Now I need to trigger the api, get information on the cluster the tests will be run against and inject those information into each of the molecule steps.

First I though about getting the connection info during the prepare step and making them global somehow (f.e. by defining them as a fact or a host_var), so the converge, verify and cleanup steps can access them.
After research and trying to build a proof-of-concept I suspect that this is not possible. Each molecule step is a new invokation of ansible-playbook, so information can't be passed around.

Am I'm completely missing possibilites molecule is offering? 
Are there any suggestions on how to reach my goal?

Comment: While not what you asked, [`kind`](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kind#readme) is both amazing and _fast_ at creating essentially disposable kubernetes clusters that run inside docker